# React - loading big .json before app init for handling translations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gettext

I have an old app with translations stored in database and I'm building React app on top of it.

I decided my application will get translations from the back-end in a form of one, big .json file (not sure if there's any other, sane, scalable way, most likely - no). I can't show the app to users before the translations are in place, so I'm thinking about doing something like:

- setting up a preloader (let's say on index.html),
- fetching the .json, when fetch is success then I push the json data to localStorage,
- applying all the translations using react-gettext or something close to it,
- removing the preloader, and maybe redirecting user to the right url using react-router.

There are some problems with my masterplan though:

- what if translations don't fit in the localStorage?, what should I use for this purpose? I just want users to do the fetch only once and then I will be loading everything from their localStorage, so they won't be fetching data from the server all the time,
- won't it be REALLY slow, if we're talking about, let's say, loading MBs of json (I will try to load 400 KBs tops, but it's possible the app will grow to even 2-5 MB in translations alone),
- is react-gettext fast enough for my purpose, if we're talking about 10 000s of strings (and users have been already waiting for quite a while for json loading)?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Can you bundle this json with your app code? In our project we do it this way

Comment: Regarding fitting the translation in localStorage - you can try compressing the data (using, for example, https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string).

Another approach will be efficient caching - the user will get the data for the first time from the network, and the next time from the local cache, until a new version of the file will be available.

Comment: Hmm, are you using redux? [There is a redux helper that you might want to look into to](https://medium.com/@ryandrewjohnson/adding-multi-language-support-to-your-react-redux-app-cf6e64250050). I would load the app and by default show the preloader. In the background, fetch the json and then store it in your app state. Once you have your state populated, then you can apply `react-gettext` to translate and then you can either redirect the user to use conditional render in your main App component.

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk it will be dynamically fetched from the database so I'm afraid I can't (the translations will change, not sure how often). Giad Artzi, thanks I will check it out! Chase DeAnda not sure about Redux, the app is quite simple (only a few views, not much state per se).